# Rest api design: how to design api to block different type of communication?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, api-design

We have an e-commerce website where users can register. To avoid spamming, we want to create APIs to block certain mobile number, IPs, IMEIs. We are confused between two API designs:

1. Create API to block these communications i.e. single API capable to block IP/Mobile/IMEI

   POST /api/blockcommunication/

   In POST request body, it receives an array of objects having information like:

   i.e. type: what type of blocking it is 1 for number, 2 for IP, 3 for IMEI

   AND value: i.e. if type is 1, this expects number. If type is 2, this expects IP. If type is 3, this expects IMEI.
2. Create separate APIs i.e. POST /api/blockmobile, POST /api/blockip/. These APIs take array of mobiles, IPs respectively in their request body.

Pro of approach1 is that we have central API to block anything and we can extend it to further block emails, whatsapp-communications etc. but this would become more complex as more request fields are added. Approach2 might not have central point to block communication but looks simple and clean.

Which of these 2 is better OR any other approach to design such api?

Comment: Why do you wanna share that informations? This blockades for me should be handled by backend on requests. But if you wanna make this enpoints available to see what is currently blocked for admins I would design it like /api/blockade and then add filter by ?type

Comment: There's some confusion here.. editted the question. i want to create these APIs to save blocked information and not share it. Its a post request and not get

Comment: See, So i would go the first way as is probably describe object which have fileds like value and type but also named is as blockade, also would consider adding level of blockade for example something that describe "he can access web pages but can't use chat"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first approach would be more scalable but at the risk of becoming a huge monolithic block of decision making. Can the central API work out the type from the data? i.e. can it work out whether it's an IP, mobile or IMEI? If so, don't send the type, just send the data and let the central API decide what to do with it. That way you can add more types without the clients who want these things blocked knowing about the new types, just send the data.

You could then scale out by combining the two API approaches. The central API then sends to /api/blockmobile etc once it's worked out what the type is.

So the clients just say "I don't want to see this again" and the central API works out what type it is and sends to that type blocking API

Answer (score 0):

I think an endpoint such as `/api/blocked-clients` will do the trick.

Perform a `POST` request with a representation of the client that must be blocked. On my understanding, you could send `type` and `value` attributes:

```
POST /api/blocked-clients
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "ip",
  "value": "0.0.0.0"
}
```

If the operation has succeeded, the response should contain the `201` status code and a `Location` header with a URI that identifies the newly created resource such as `/api/blocked-clients/{id}` (where `{id}` is a unique identifier).

You also can support `GET` operations in the `/api/blocked-clients` endpoint, so you can get a representation of all clients that have been blocked. A response would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "ip",
    "value": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "imei",
    "value": "000000000000"
  }
]
```

You also could support `DELETE` operations in the `/api/blocked-clients/{id}` endpoint.

Comment: don't you think as different type of communication enters, we will have to modify this API.. this might lead to changes in this API and retesting of this.. what's the problem in having different APIs?

Comment: @maverick _(...) as different type of communication enters, we will have to modify this API.. this might lead to changes in this API and retesting of this (...)_ So you already **know the answer for your question**. However, for the situation you described, you currently only have _type_ and _value_.

Comment: in the request body we will have type, value, modules, blockeduntil etc. things AND we will keep on adding type i.e. whatsapp etc. in future.... should we still keep all this in one single API?

Comment: @maverick Does a single endpoint suit your needs? Then the answer is _yes_.